# Pandas read_pickle, UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\xfd'

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read in my pickle file , however I am getting the following error `UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\xfd'.` Does anyone know how to solve this?

```
import pandas as pd

file = r"O:\Stack\Over\Flow\202210_Other.pkl"
test = pd.read_pickle(file)
print(test)
```

Any advice would be appeciated.

Comment: How, exactly, was that pickle file created?  Was it written with the exact same version of Python you are using to read it?

Comment: that is a good question - i did not create the pickle file. My code has worked with other pickle files though.

Comment: perhaps it was compressed? pd.read_pickle(file, compression="gzip")

Comment: Are you able to read it with the standard pickle module, not the Pandas one?

Comment: @JasonBaker getting error `BadGzipFile: Not a gzipped file (b'\xfd7')` when using `test = pd.read_pickle(file, compression="gzip")`

Answer (score 0):

Was able to figure it out, it was

pd.read_pickle(file, compression="xz")